# How to find out what files were output by a list of ksh scripts?

Tags: unix, aix

Is it possible find out what files were produced by a particular script by just having it's pid ?

```
input:
scriptA.ksh pid: 1234

output:
scriptA.log
```

OS version: AIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`truss`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/truss.htm) (similar to `strace` on Linux) for this.

```
truss scriptA.ksh 2>&1 | grep open
```

You'll have to sift through some unrelated calls to `open()`, but your log files will be in there.

Also, `truss` can attach to existing processes by using the `-p` switch.

Note: I speak from experience with `strace`, but it looks like this all holds for `truss`...

Comment: I'd recommend also using `-f` flags, otherwise `strace` will only monitor the parent process without paying any attention to children.

Comment: `strace` is not the same thing on AIX.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds5%2Fstrace.htm